# the filename .xls is not readable

Tags: php

I want to download file .xls and then upload it to database oracle. but I am getting an error "the filename .xls is not readable".

Below is my script:

```
               <? require_once (dirname(__FILE__)."/upload/upBc.php");

               if(!empty($_FILES["file"])){
                    echo $file = $_FILES["file"];
               }else{
                  /*$file = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/avar/pp/ccr/test.xls";*/
                     $file = '/www.upload.com/pm_ms/test.xls';
               /* $file = "website_data_".  date('ymd').".xls";*/



               }
                    $upload = new upload();
                    $upload->setFile($file);
                    $upload->getFileType();
                    $upload->getFileName();
                    $upload->getFileDir();
                    $upload->readDataTbc();
                    $dataD = array ();
                    $dataD = $upload->getDataTbc();
                        echo "<table border = 1>";
                        for($i=1;$i < count($dataD);$i++){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            for($j=0;$j < $upload->getHSize();$j++){
                                echo "  <td>".$dataD[$i][$j]."</td>";
                            }
                            echo"</tr>";
                          }
                          echo"</table>";
                          echo"data length=". count($dataD);
                          $upload->commitDataTbc();


       ?>
```

If I use `$file = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/avar/pp/ccr/test.xls";`. in my program it works
but if I use `$file = '/www.upload.com/pm_ms/test.xls';`. I get the error THE FILENAME test.xls is Not Readable

Comment: don't just apply random tags to your post, this has nothing to do with javascript/jquery/oracle or MySQL - it's a php question

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `/www.upload.com/` doesn't exist on your server.

Do you know the actual path to the file? By prefixing the URI with `/` this makes it absolute, which means that it's trying to read literally from `/www.upload.com` on your server. If you're looking to make this relative you could try `./upload.com/` or simply `upload.com/` as the path prefix.

If you are however trying to load it from the website upload.com (instead of a folder from your server) you have two options:

1. (If Supported) Set the filename as a URL ie. `$file = 'http://www.upload.com/pm_ms/test.xls';`
2. Download the file and then open it locally.

For #2:

```
$file = 'test.xls';
$ctnts = file_get_contents('http://www.upload.com/pm_ms/test.xls');
file_put_contents($file, $ctnts);
```

Comment: where i have to change path in my code . I am working in localhost.